# Force code reloading before each request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Ruby on Rails 5 and I'm wondering how can I force code reloading before each request. The reason I need this is that I'm using Docker on Mac and my code lives in a NFS folder, thus the Rails mechanism for detecting code changes isn't working properly and I must reboot rails after each code change.

So, my question is: How can I force Rails to reload my code before each request?

Comment: Do you have `rb-fsevent` gem installed?

Comment: @maicher No, but I don't see how would that help. No filesystem tool/monitor will help me as the code lives in a NFS folder and rails is running inside Docker. FiIe change events just won't be created/delivered.

Comment: Does `config.cache_classes = false` help? According to the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html), `config.cache_classes` controls whether or not application classes and modules should be reloaded on each request.

Comment: The new Rails 5 development mode for code change reloading is opt-in (http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2015/11/11/snappier-development-mode-in-rails-5/), so the fact that this is rails 5 should I think, be irrelevant. I suspect you are editing some code which is outside the `app` folder, and therefore needs to be added to the autoload paths configuration(http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html). However, beyond that I'm honestly not sure what could cause/solve this.

Comment: @Aetherus `cache_classes = false` doesn't help. @Tom Lord, no, I'm editing a controller inside the `app` folder.

Comment: Worst case scenario: You could set up a local listener that stamps out `tmp/restart.txt` each time you save something.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using the [rerun gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/rerun). This will allow you to reload a rack application on code change. Since Rails is basically a complex rack application this should work.

This will reload the entire(!) rails application every time, but it will reload.

I'm currently using it in a grape API, where I'm running it like this, and you should be able to run your rails application the same way.

```
bundle exec rerun 'rackup'
```

PS: You might want additional parameters such as port, etc. there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution on Rails 5.

You can use [rerun gem](https://github.com/alexch/rerun) with the following setup :

Add `gem rerun` in your `Gemfile`

Launch server with `rerun rails s`

The following [options](https://github.com/alexch/rerun/#options) may be usefull :

- `--dir` : allow to watch a specific directory and reload on change
- `--background` : rerun won't read the keyboard and let you use debugger like `byebug`